# Australia Region Repeat

Tags: magento2

State Region Repeat 2 time like I have western Australia in Region Dropdown but its repeat 2 time so I want to delete one western Australia how I do this.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to go phpmyadmin

open table **directory_country_region**

search country_id = AU

you get all the record related to country Austaliya ,delete the record that you want